# Integration of vue.js with laravel 5.4 and upper

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router

I am new in vue.js and trying to work with laravel. I have some question regarding that. If anyone give feedback, then it will better for my learning.

1. **npm run watch**. Is this command necessary for every modification of my code? I am facing that issue. If I modify or add something , it doesn't show expected output. it shows [vue warn] Unknown custom: element ......
2. I've followed this steps to install.
   Firstly I install node js from https://nodejs.org/en/ . Then did **npm install** in command prompt. is this right way ?
3. When I'll deploy this project is shared hosting server, is this as-usual of laravel project deployment or more ?

Thanks is advance ....

Comment: `npm run watch` will do just what it sounds like it will watch for any changes you make in your code and automatically build them.  You need to execute the command and leave it running.  By default it watches the files in `your project > resources > assets`

Comment: The error `[vue warn] Unknown custom: element ...`   is likely being caused by you using a custom element like `<my-cool-element></my-cool-element>` but not properly importing that element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I'll deploy this project is shared hosting server, is this as-usual of laravel project deployment or more ?